# Download file from Amazon S3 to lambda and extract it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to download a zip file from AWS Amazon S3 and download it on lambda. But I cannot find the downloaded file or it's not downloading. The file has all the necessary permissions.

My code:

```
 const file = require('fs').createWriteStream('/tmp/temp0.zip');
 s3.getObject({
  Bucket: 'myBucket',
  Key: 'temp0.zip',
 }).createReadStream().pipe(file);
 file.on('close', function() {
   fs.readdir('./', (err, files) => {
    files.forEach((file) => {
      console.log('File: ', file);
    });
  });
 });
```

When I run it, it does not log the file name. I also tried to read `tmp` folder, and I couldn't. My user has all the necessary permissions to download the file. How can I do this?

Comment: You say your user has the necessary permissions, what about your Lambda function? What rights does it's role have?

Comment: my lambda function has also the necessary role to read and write. I`m trying to download this zip file from s3 and unzip it on lambda everything lambda is called, is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by *"download it on lambda"*?

Comment: I just discovery that I can only get from s3 in lambda in the folder `/tmp/`. Thats solve my problem